# Select an iframe, if the parent element has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this piece of jQuery inside one of my methods:

```
videos: $('iframe[src*="vimeo"], iframe[src*="youtube"]'),
```

What it currently does is select all `<iframe>` elements with the `src` containing `youtube`.

Here is what I'm attempting to do:

Select all the `<iframe>` elements with the `src` containing `youtube` and NOT containing the `modal` class in the parent element.

So let's say that I have this:
[image]

If it has the `modal` class inside the `<section>` don't select the `<iframe>`.

Comment: Try using the [not pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). `section:not(.modal) iframe[src*="youtube"]`

Answer (score 0):

Although I think jQuery has a specific way to do this, you can also use the CSS [not pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

```js
const iframes = $('section:not(.modal) iframe[src*="vimeo"], section:not(.modal) iframe[src*="youtube"]');
```

Please note that this will work if *any* parent/ancestor section does not have the `modal` class.

If you need it to be the direct parent, use:

```js
const iframes = $('*:not(.modal) > iframe[src*="vimeo"], *:not(.modal) > iframe[src*="youtube"]');
```

I've also used the `*` [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) so it's not specific to the `section` element.